# Cannot start service <MyService> on computer '.' C#

Tags: c#, windows, service

I so Confused Why My windows service not Starting! My Service not starting that is work a later but now not working anybody have
solution to this problem MY Exception is  **"Cannot start service
  on computer '.'."**  and My innerExceoption is  **" The
 Service did not respond to start or control in a timely fashion."**

> > I observe UAC(User Access Control) in windows my visual studio is run as
> >     admin and Before starting Service  I install Service by args in main
> >     Method!

```
 using System;
 using System.Linq;
 using System.Reflection;
 using System.ServiceProcess;
 using System.Windows.Forms;
 namespace BotTelegram
        {
         static void Main(string [] args)
                {    
            if (args.Contains("-i"))
                            {
                                System.Configuration.Install.AssemblyInstaller installer =
                                    new System.Configuration.Install.AssemblyInstaller(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location, null)
                                    {
                                        UseNewContext = true
                                    };
                                installer.Install(null);
                                installer.Commit(null);
                                if (!args.Contains("nomessage"))
                                    System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(@"Installed Successfully!");
                                Console.WriteLine(@"Installed Successfully!");
                                return;
                            }
                            if (args.Contains("-u"))
                            {
                                System.Configuration.Install.AssemblyInstaller installer =
                                    new System.Configuration.Install.AssemblyInstaller(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location, null)
                                    {
                                        UseNewContext = true
                                    };
                                installer.Uninstall(null);
                                if (!args.Contains("nomessage"))
                                    System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(@"Removed Successfully!");
                                Console.WriteLine(@"Removed Successfully!");
                                return;
                            }
                            if (args.Contains("-s1"))
                            {
                                var service = new ServiceController("PriceCheckerService", ".");
                                try
                                {
                                    if (service.Status == ServiceControllerStatus.Stopped)
                                    {
                                        service.Start();
                                        if (!args.Contains("nomessage"))
                                            System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(@"Start Service!!");
                                        return;
                                    }

                                }

                                finally
                                {
                                    service.Close();
                                }
                                try
                                {
                                    if (service.Status == ServiceControllerStatus.Running)
                                    {
                                        if (service.CanStop)
                                        {
                                            service.Stop();
                                            if (!args.Contains("nomessage"))
                                                System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(@"Stopped Service!!");
                                            return;
                                        }
                                    }

                                }
                                finally
                                {
                                    service.Close();
                                }

                            }

                              ServiceBase[] ServicesToRun;
                    ServicesToRun = new ServiceBase[]
                    {
                        new    ServiceBase[] ServicesToRun;
                    ServicesToRun = new ServiceBase[]
                    {
                        new PriceCheckerService()
                    };
                    ServiceBase.Run(ServicesToRun);()
                    };
                    ServiceBase.Run(ServicesToRun);

                    }
        }
```

Comment: Can you tell us which on line you are getting exception?

Comment: Format your code, this won't even compile.

Comment: @Deepak when  condition  "args. contains ("-s1") " is true and 
in line "service.start();"